# Visual Studio 2017: классы отличающиеся именем от физического пути файла вызывают ошибки

Tags: visual-studio, build-error

В проекте есть несколько файлов которые различаются именем от имени класса.

Например:

TestClassA.cs имеет имя физического файла Test**c**lassA.cs

Visual Studio подгружает этот класс в проект, его видно в Solution Explorer-e, но его нельзя открыть. При этом если удалить файл из проекта то он удаляется и на диске. Т.е. какая-то связь между ними есть.

При компиляции возникают ошибки вида:
Could not find file TestClassA.cs

На другой машине проект компилируется без проблем.

Build/Rebuild/Clean/удаление всех .vs папок/удаление кэшей не помогло

Что можно сделать?